# Unable to login using qtnetworkaccessmanager but able using postman tool

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qnetworkaccessmanager to login to a website, i am setting user and password in rowHeader but getting empty response in code, but the same request with user and password set in header works properly using Postman tool, can anyone suggest what could be the issue ?

```
QString user = "user";
QString pass = "testPassword";
QByteArray data1 = user.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QByteArray data2 = pass.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://server_address/b1/login"));

request.setRawHeader("user", data1);
request.setRawHeader("password", data2);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
```

and i am fetching reply using below code -

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
this, [=](QNetworkReply *reply) {
if (reply->error()) {
qDebug() << reply->errorString();
return;
}

    QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << answer;

    bool isFinished = reply->isFinished();
    bool isRunning = reply->isRunning();
    QNetworkReply::NetworkError err = reply->error();
QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
QString str(bts);
qDebug() << str;
```

Below is the postman screenshot with headers

[image: Postman image]

Comment: show how is the configuration of postman

Comment: Are you actually setting the user and password as values in the request header? If so, please post a screenshot, or the information, of the Postman header values. Thanks!

Comment: Added image for postman config/parameter details.

Comment: @Pallavi Why the data to base64?

Comment: @eyllanesc : Got that code from net, so used as is for testing, tried without bast64 as well.

Comment: @Pallavi mmmm, remove `ByteArray data1 = user.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QByteArray data2 = pass.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();` and change to `request.setRawHeader("user", user);
request.setRawHeader("password", pass);`

Comment: You probably need other headers too like content-length

Comment: @Nina: i tried to set content length still response is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
QString user = "testUser"; // Use same "user" value as you used in your Postman example
QString pass = "testPassword";
QByteArray data1 = user.toLocal8Bit(); // Remove toBase64()
QByteArray data2 = pass.toLocal8Bit(); // Remove toBase64()
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://server_address/b1/login"));

request.setRawHeader("user", data1);
request.setRawHeader("password", data2);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
```

Comment: Thanks ManuelH, I tried same code but still its not working :( I think setRawHeader is not working properly. because the APIs (not having headers as a input) are working fine in my code, it is failing in case of headers.

Comment: In that case, use Wireshark to intercept the raw HTTP request from the Qt application and inspect it. Then compare it to the raw HTTP request from Postman.